# code inside jButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method is not working

Tags: java, swing

I have a `jTextField`, `jLabel` and a `jButton`. I want to set the `jTextField` to empty and update the `jLabel` to some new text after I perform `jButton` action.

This my code for jButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method:

```
private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    BufferedWriter fw;
    StringBuilder guessword = new StringBuilder(word);

    try {
        fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Arihant\\JavaApplication1\\src\\javaapplication1\\scores.txt", true));

        while(guesses != 0) {
            jLabel26.setText(Integer.toString(guesses));
            guesschar = jTextField2.getText().charAt(0);
            flag = 0;

            for(int j = 0; j < word.length() / 2; j++) {                    
                if(Character.toLowerCase(guesschar) == temp[j] && (guessword.toString().indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(guesschar)) < 0)) {
                    flag = 1;

                    for(int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++) {
                        if(Character.toLowerCase(guesschar) == word.charAt(k))
                            guessword.setCharAt(k, Character.toLowerCase(guesschar));
                    }
                    if(guessword.toString().equals(word)) {                            
                        switch (difficulty) {
                            case "EASY":
                                points = guesses * 50;
                                break;
                            case "MODERATE":
                                points = guesses * 100;
                                break;
                            case "HARD":
                                points = guesses * 200;
                                break;
                            default:
                                points = 0;
                                break;
                        }

                        try {
                            fw.append(name + " " + points);
                            fw.newLine();
                            fw.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(HangMan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            System.out.println(ex);
                        }

                        jPanel13.removeAll();
                        jPanel13.add(jPanel4);
                        jPanel13.repaint();
                        jPanel13.revalidate();
                        jLabel29.setText("<html>YOU WIN!<br/> The word was: </html>" + word);
                        jLabel31.setText("You scored: " + points + " points.");
                        jLabel28.setText("Play again?");
                    }
                }
            }
            if(flag == 0) {
                guesses--;
            }
            jPanel13.repaint();
            jPanel13.revalidate();
            jLabel1.setText(guessword.toString());
            jTextField2.setText("");
            Document document = jTextField2.getDocument();
            document.addDocumentListener(new JButtonStateController(jButton8, 0));
            ((AbstractDocument) jTextField2.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new JTextFieldFilter(0));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HangMan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);   
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

When I click `jButton8`, it just skips the entire code in `try-catch` block and goes directly to `jPanel13.removeAll();`.

I want to set the `jTextField2` to empty and `jButton8` to disabled, each time I click `jButton8`.

Tell me, where I am wrong and how can I improve my code?

Comment: Did it went through `System.out.println("guessed whole word");` ?

Comment: I added the printStreams to watch the code, but no, it didn't went through `System.out.println("guessed whole word");`. It skips the entire `try-catch` block!

Comment: What is the inital value of `guesses`? Could it be `0`?

Comment: perhaps `guesses` is zero

Comment: I had added the following code to initialize the `guesses` using `jRadioButtons`

`private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        difficulty = "EASY";
        guesses = 8;
    }                                             
   ...`

Comment: Can you include the whole code in your question? It will be easier to find the problem if we have the whole code and not just fragments

Comment: Okay, I got it, when `jRadioButton1` is set to default, value of `guesses` is not initialized. I edit my code, and it's working fine now. Just that, I wanted to know how to reset `jTextField2` (set as empty) and `jButton8`(set as disabled) to previous states after `jButton8` action?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, any help?

Comment: `jTextField2.setText("");` and `jButton8.setEnabled(false);` after try-catch

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, look at the question again (I made some changes). The `while-loop` is running until guesses reaches 0 taking first `guesschar` as all guessed character (I mean, not waiting for input). How to make the loop to wait for input.

Basically, what I am trying to do here is, take an input from user in `guesschar` and check if it present in the formattedWord (original word with dashes), if yes then update my `jLabel` else decrement the `guesses`. Any help?

Comment: I think you should use `JOptionPane` or `Scanner` if you want to take user input. If you want a GUI solution, either use `JOptionPane` or a custom **`modal`** dialog to delay the execution of the method. Else set a fixed time with `Thread.sleep()` or something similar

Comment: Got it, I removed the while loop and made some few changes (variables values) and it's working great. By the way this is my first GUI program. So far, I have completed 20% of my project. Thanks to your help! @XtremeBaumer

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).